# Absolutely Positioned Divs Extending Past the Footer

Tags: html, css

Here's the css:

```
#content-wrapper {clear:both;}
#shell {width:100%;}
* html #content-wrapper { float:left;height: 100%; }
#page-outer{margin:0 auto;}
#page-content {margin:0 0.7%;}
```

Here's the css.

Comment: If you make the changes I've described below the page you linked to above will work...

Comment: We need your html as well. ...Btw, nowhere in your css is any absolute position div your refer to in your title?

Answer (score 0):

For removing overlapping you have to write `<br clear='all' />` above and below the overlapped html code

OR

Write `clear:both` in overlapped element style

Comment: How can you tell without seeing the html? ... And the clear attribute is a deprecated. Please revise or delete to avoid down votes.